# Return Boolean per row, if index in ColumnN specifies the column with the lowest number (from columns 1 to N-1)

Tags: mysql, sql

My database looks like this:

[image]

The first three columns are odds (as in probability). The fourth column refers to one of the first three columns.

I need to know if column four, in each row, refers to the column with the lowest value out of the first three. The query to check this should return a boolean result: true if column four refers to the column with the lowest value, false otherwise.

For example:

- Row 1's lowest value is 1.7, in column 1. Column four in this row **1**. Result: true.
- Row 5's lowest value is 1.71, in column 1. Column four in this row is **2**. Result: false.

Comment: This is very confusing. What is the comparison you want? You want to compare column 1 with what? You want to only check rows that what? Which columns are the ones with odds???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with a CASE statement and comparison.

You would use case to select the value of the column with specified by column 4, and check whether this is the smallest of the 3 columns.

Something along the lines of:

```
select 
CASE 
WHEN COLUMN4 = 1 THEN COLUMN1 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
WHEN COLUMN4 = 2 THEN COLUMN2 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
WHEN COLUMN4 = 3 THEN COLUMN3 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
END
from TABLE;
```

**Update:**

Here is also an SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61c18/5

Updated SQL to display text as 'true' and 'false'

```
select 
IF(
CASE 
WHEN COLUMN4 = 1 THEN COLUMN1 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
WHEN COLUMN4 = 2 THEN COLUMN2 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
WHEN COLUMN4 = 3 THEN COLUMN3 = LEAST(COLUMN1,COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
END
,
'true','false')
as FOUND_SMALLEST
from TEST;
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle is amazing :) So is StackOverflow because I also saw it here :)). Also enjoy: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT (LEAST(col1, col2, col3) > col4) as result FROM whatever_table_this_is;`

Comment: You misunderstand. He wants to know if the number in col4 is the number of the column with the lowest value of the three. e.g. if the first column is the min it should be 1, if the second column is the min it should be 2, if the third column is the min it should be 3.

Comment: Right Patashu, my explanation are a bit confusing I must admit

Comment: Not as I understand it, since he wants `TRUE` or `FALSE`, as indicated when he said “The final goal is to get a true or false, whether the lowest number is in the column indicated in column 4 or not.”. @user2158360 You really need to ask the right question. I've flagged this for closing as this question is very vague and now contradicts itself.

Comment: Column 4 is a value of a column 1 means column 1, 2 means column 2, 3 means column 3

Comment: @coreyward "whether the lowest number is in the column indicated in column 4 or not." He means, if the lowest number was from column X, column 4 should have X to return true, else return false.